# send mail when Anonymous Authentication for SMTP server

Tags: c#, authentication, anonymous

```
  //   Send anonymous e-mail using SMTP Server (c# code ) 
 //setting SmtpClient property
     SmtpClient smtpClient =new  SmtpClient();
              smtpClient .Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtpClient .Port = 587;
                    smtpClient .EnableSsl = true;
           smtpClient .DeliveryMethod =SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpClient .UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                smtpClient .Timeout =  30000;

      //setting MailMessage property
              MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                 mailMessage.Subject = "test mail";
           mailMessage.From = (new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com"));
                    mailMessage.To.Add("xyz@gmail.com");
                    mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

                        mailMessage.Body = "Hello";

                      smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Basically, I'm trying to send mail when Authentication is Anonymous. if I pass username and password then e-mail send successfully but if I remove username and password credential (i.e Authentication is Anonymous) then I fail to send mail.

Comment: You should set:
smtpClient .UseDefaultCredentials = true;

Comment: I want to send anonymous mail so from msdn If the UseDefaultCredentials property is set to false and the Credentials property has not been set, then mail is sent to the server anonymously. @Poul Bak